# Show alert dialog onMarkerClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, material-ui, google-maps-markers

I have a for-loop that plots markers for each of the entries in my database. However, I want to make it so that, when clicked, each marker displays the information specific to that marker (information retrieved from the database) on a Material Alert Dialog.

Right now, I am trying to do that by putting the information I want in a tag on the marker when it is created. Then, when creating the Alert Dialog, I get the information from the tag and put it on the Dialog.

However, this has not worked. When I click on a marker, no matter what marker it is, it always goes directly to the else statement in the click listener - it displays a Toast message saying "Other."

There is no error message, but it is not working.

How can I fix this so that I can display the information specific to each marker on an Alert Dialog when each marker is clicked?

Here is my code:

```
redColRef.get(source)
   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                   java.util.Map<String, Object> mapOfPins = (HashMap<String, Object>) document.get("Location");


                   if (mapOfPins != null) {
                       Log.d(TAG, mapOfPins.get("latitude") + ", " + mapOfPins.get("longitude"));
                      pins = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(mapOfPins.get("latitude").toString()), Double.valueOf(mapOfPins.get("longitude").toString()));
                       direction = document.get("Direction").toString();
                       sender = document.get("Sender").toString();
                       java.util.Map<String, Object> detailsTag = new HashMap();
                       detailsTag.put("Location", pins);
                       detailsTag.put("Direction", direction);
                       detailsTag.put("Sender", sender);
                       switch (direction) {
                           case "North":
                           case "South":
                               map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                       .title("Pole Pin")
                                       .zIndex(0.6f)
                                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yellow))
                                       .position(pins));
// I realize that the "setTag()" is outside of the "addMarker()" so it doesn't work. But, I'm not sure how to fix that so that the tag is set.
                                       .setTag(detailsTag);

                               break;
                           case "East":
                           case "West":
                               map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                       .title("East-West Pin")
                                       .zIndex(0.7f)
                                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.orange))
                                       .position(pins))
                                       .setTag(detailsTag);
                               break;
                           case "Other":
                               map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                       .title("Other Pin")
                                       .zIndex(0.8f)
                                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red))
                                       .position(pins))
                                       .setTag(detailsTag);
                               break;

                       }

                   }
               }
           } else {
               Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
           }
       }
   });

map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                               @Override
                               public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                   if (marker.getTag() != null) {
                                       if (marker.getTitle().toString() == "Pole Pin") {

                                           java.util.Map markerDetails= (HashMap) marker.getTag();

                                       new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                                               .setTitle("Pole Pin")
                                               .setMessage("Location: " + markerDetails.get("Location").toString() + "\n Direction: " + markerDetails.get("Direction") + "\n Sender: " + markerDetails.get("Sender"))
                                               .setPositiveButton("View Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                       Intent inte = new Intent(getActivity(), login.class);
                                                       startActivity(inte);
                                                   }
                                               })
                                               .show();
                                   } else {
                                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       }
                               }

                                   return true;
                               }
                           });
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your code not working? What's the issue?

Comment: <it always goes directly to the else statement in the click listener> So doesn't that mean that the ```if``` part is ```null```?

Comment: @PrinceAli Yes, the if-part is presumably null. But, I'm confused as to why and how I can fix that. If the marker has the title of "Pole Pin," then it shouldn't be null, right? What did I do wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to set a tag is to get the `Marker` result of `addMarker` and then invoke `.setTag()`:

```
Marker m = map.addMarker(
                 new MarkerOptions()
                       .title("Pole Pin")
                       .zIndex(0.6f)
                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yellow))
                       .position(pins));
m.setTag(detailsTag);
```

Do the same for each case.

Here's the API for the `Marker` class: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

---

I also notice your string comparisons are wrong, use this instead:

```
if (marker.getTitle().equals("Pole Pin")) {
    //...
}
```

Briefly, the `==` is reference equality (same instance) and `equals` is value equality.  (You also don't need the `toString`.) For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2711811

Comment: thank you for the response! But, I'm still confused about how I can add a different tag to each marker in a loop if I'm not defining each one separately?

Comment: When you add a marker it returns a new marker object.  Simply update your code as above (to receive the result and to set the tag) and each added marker will be assigned the corresponding detailsTag created inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it.